# Coding in Python remotely using Visual Studio Community and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to code in Python using Visual Studio Community 2019.

I'm trying to find a way to code using Visual Studio on my Windows PC, and send-run-debug the application directly on my Raspberry Pi.

Is there a way to do this? I'm finding a lot of online tutorial that shows how to *connect* Visual Studio Code to a Raspberry Pi, but I can't find anything for Visual Studio Community.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821699/can-visual-studio-not-vs-code-do-remote-ssh-development-the-docs-says-yes-bu I don't think there is such feature even now

Answer (score 0):

**VS code don't have any thing called send-run-debug**,
rather VS code is just an editor which is common for all the languages
u can use IntelliJ IDEA for debug purpose and try to connect with raspberry Pi

[debug in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gS7l.png)